# How do I interpret a getter method used as a parameter?

Tags: java

I have a bit of Java code that I can't follow.  Two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`, structured like this:

```
ClassA {

    void setName() {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void writeFunction(Object value) {
        String v = value.toString();
    }
}
```

and

```
ClassB extends ClassA {
    ...
    writeFunction( getName() );
    ...
}
```

I've never seen a getter method used without an object reference, so I'm not certain what's happening here.  `getName()` can only refer to `ClassA.getName()`.  My understanding is that methods can't be passed as parameters in Java, which means that the argument to `writeFunction()` must be the result of the method, presumably as `this.getName`?

Can anyone make an educated guess what's happening here?  JavaBeans and JSP tag libraries are involved, if that means anything.

**Edit:** Added details to code

Comment: It uses `this` as reference.

Comment: It is indeed `this.getName()`.

Comment: This is incomplete code. Return types are important. That said, no, you can't pass methods as parameters, but you can pass what they return as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an instance method from within the class that defines it calls it on the current instance (i.e. `this`). Here, you call `getName()` on the current `ClassB` object (the method is inherited from the super-class, `ClassA`), and then pass the returned value to `writeObject`.

Comment: All right, thanks!  Now that I know what's happening, I have a follow-up question: setName() is never called within the entire code base, based on grepping the whole thing for "setName(".  Both `getName()` and `setName()` are ordinary getter/setter methods, as edited above.  Do you have any idea how `getName()` could be returning a non-null value?